# Detect SFTP file upload completed

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, debian, sftp

I have an SFTP server (debian ssh server) where remote users are uploading once a while one big file into a specific directory.

My challenge is that I need to detect:

1) that a new file is present.

2) that the upload process/transmission is done.

What would be the best way to do this? Maybe there is already some tools available for this?

Logically thinking I can maybe detect in a first phase that a new file is present in the directory. And in a second phase then loop/wait until the user SFTP disconnects!? After that I could fire the next process...

Thx & cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For problem 1) you can use the `inotify` API to watch the directory for changes. You don't say which programming language you use. In Perl you would use `Linux::Inotify`, in Python `pynotify`.

For problem 2), one way is to wait until the ssh session disconnects, another is to also use `inotify` to watch for file close notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar situation. Although I used JSCH but the approach might help.

You may upload the file with some temporary extension. e.g. **bigFile.txt.temp** . Once the file is uploaded, [rename](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/) it to the desired file name i.e **bigFile.txt** and delete the temporary file. [JSCH ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/). In JSCH, rename does the job of keeping only one file. So you need not explicitly delete the temporary file.

Before uploading any newer version of the file, check for the existence of the temporary file - bigFile.txt.temp. If it exists, that means the file is currently getting uploaded. set a reply code or wait for the session to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, it's enough to see if any users are currently connected through SFTP. If so, I'll simply consider all files locked.

This can be done (in Linux/OpenSSH) through a `ps -ef` command in the way described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/321035/how-can-i-see-if-users-are-logged-in-over-sftp).

Cheers!